# What does a seminar host typically do?

Tags: mathematics, united-states, seminars

At the weekly seminars in my department, for any professor who's flying in to town this semester, there's typically a professor from our department that is the "host" for this seminar speaker.
And each week, there is a different host, for different seminar speakers coming to town.

What is the typical responsibilities of a host?

For instance, do they arrange for social activity (dinners?) for the seminar speaker, before and after their talk?

This is in reference to U.S. universities, math departments.

Comment: This varies a lot by institution. Ask locally if you have a need to know.

Comment: @Buffy I just clarified my question, hope that helps.

Comment: I meant "really" locally. One university in NYC might have completely different traditions than another in the same city. My basic guess is that the "host" is the one that invited the speaker. It might be nothing more than that.

Comment: This is so local I'm voting to close for 'depends on individual factors'.  This could be wildly different between the Harvard math dept and the MIT math dept, different between the MIT math dept and the MIT CS/EE dept, and even different between the MIT combinatorics seminar and the MIT representation theory seminar.

Comment: @AlexanderWoo, yep. _really_ **really** local.

Comment: I disagree with the "too specific". I've given seminar talks at many different universities in several different countries, and there is a very clear standard pattern for how this works.

Comment: @Arno The question is not how giving seminars work, the question is what the role of the host is.

Comment: @user151413 I am very well aware of that, and "this" in my comment refers to the role of the host.